# Populating std::array in class' constructor initializer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ctor-initializer, stdarray

Is there a way to populate a `std::array` in a class' constructor initializer?

Right now I'm populating it the long way:

```
class Matrix3x3 {
//...
private:
    std::array<double, 9> _indicies;
};
//...
Matrix3x3::Matrix3x3(double m00, double m01, double m02, double m10, double m11, double m12, double m20, double m21, double m22) : _indicies() {
    _indicies[0] = m00; _indicies[1] = m01; _indicies[2] = m02;
    _indicies[3] = m10; _indicies[4] = m11; _indicies[5] = m12;
    _indicies[6] = m20; _indicies[7] = m21; _indicies[8] = m22;
}
```

-EDIT--

Visual Studio 2010 does not have full c++11 support (it still lists std::array as a typedef to the `std::tr1::array` namespace!).

Attempts include:

```
1. Matrix3x3::Matrix3x3(const std::initializer_list<std::array<double, 9> >& row_column_values) : _indicies(row_column_values) { }
2. Matrix3x3::Matrix3x3(double m00, double m01, double m02, double m10, double m11, double m12, double m20, double m21, double m22) : _indicies({m00, m01, m02, m10, m11, m12, m20, m21, m22}) { }
```

None of which work in VS2010. All of them report errors:

```
1. error C2664: 'std::tr1::array<_Ty,_Size>::array(const std::tr1::array<_Ty,_Size> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::initializer_list<_Elem>' to 'const std::tr1::array<_Ty,_Size> &'
2. Cascading errors:
    error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
    error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
    error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Comment: Use a constructor initializer list.

Comment: Think about just having your constructor take a std::initializer_list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 you can use a curly brace initializer, like this:

```
Matrix3x3::Matrix3x3(double m00, double m01, double m02, double m10, double m11, double m12, double m20, double m21, double m22)
:   _indicies({m00, m01, m02, m10, m11, m12, m20, m21, m22}) {
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/DSgntD)

Comment: The surrounding parentheses shouldn't be there. I have some backing for that somewhere if I can find it, although Clang does complain.

Comment: @chris The code wouldn't compile without the braces - here is a [link to my attempt to remove curly braces on ideone](http://ideone.com/sG9qR4).

Comment: Unless I'm just thinking of normal arrays. That could very well be the case. Seems my claim of Clang complaining [only holds](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e006b7ff721da78c) for a normal array. It still compiles with no parentheses and `std::array`, but no warning with the parentheses for that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You was fast, too fast for me ;)

Comment: To add, I've already tried this in between posting and getting answers, it does not work in vs2010.

Comment: @Casey This is because VS 2010 does not support C++11, and it is not clear whether they have plans to add support any time soon - even to the C++ compiler shipped with the latest and greatest versions of the tool. This is quite unfortunate :-(

Comment: Selecting this as an answer since it will be helpful to people with vs2012(2013?) and higher who may ask the question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
array<int, 4> arr;
arr = {1,2,3,4};
```

perhaps changing your code to:

```
Matrix3x3::Matrix3x3(double m00, double m01, double m02, double m10, double m11, double m12, double m20, double m21, double m22) : _indicies({m00, m01, m02, m10, m11, m12, m20, m21, m22}) {}
```

Comment: I've already tried this in between posting and getting answers, it does not work in vs2010 (see dasblinkenlight's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic constructor

```
template<typename... A>
Matrix3x3(A&&... a) : _indicies{{std::forward<A>(a)...}} { }
```

that will accept at most 9 initializers that are implicitly convertible to `double` (except narrowing), exactly like `std::array<double, 9>`'s [aggregate-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).